# Get list of multi layered folder structure in php

Tags: php, laravel, algorithm, directory

I need to find all directories name from a network folder mapped to my system. I can successfully connect to that network directory and list all folder using php glob function. But in my case, that folder is multi layered, which means there may be multiple sub-directories under a single directory, and also more sub-directories under that sub-directories too, i. e. why I said multi-layered folder system.
So I want to ask if there's any suggestion or algorithm by which I can get the list of all directories and sub-directories of whole structure in possible shortest way in php.

Comment: Not duplicate...I dont want to search for a file...but to list folder, sub-folder, sub-sub-folder and so on...just asked any algorithm that could do it in shortest time

Comment: @iamawesome What have you tried?